# How to decode SessionSecurityToken

Tags: .net-4.5, wif, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model

Is it possible to decode a `SessionSecurityToken`?

I've set up a site to work with `ThinkTecture IdentityServer` using `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler`, and everything works as expected.
But now I need to pass the token to another service, but in an `Authorization` HTTP header instead of a cookie.

I've tried the following:

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.CookieHandler.Name];

if (cookie != null)
{
    var t = MachineKey.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(cookie.Value), "System.IdentityModel.Services.MachineKeyTransform");
}
```

but this throws a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The only (easy) way of sending the data across the wire is to convert the `SessionSecurityToken` to a `JwtSecurityToken` and use the `RawData` property.

Sample implementation (dependent on `ThinkTecture.IdentityModel`):

```
public JwtSecurityToken ConvertSessionToJsonWebSecurityToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken)
{
    var h = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers[typeof(JwtSecurityToken)] as JwtSecurityTokenHandler;

    if (h != null)
    {
        var issuer = ((ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry)h.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry).IssuingAuthorities.First().Name;
        var audience = h.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.First().AbsoluteUri;
        var signingKey = ((ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry)h.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry).IssuingAuthorities.First().SymmetricKeys.First();
        var securityKey = ((NamedKeyIssuerTokenResolver)h.Configuration.IssuerTokenResolver).SecurityKeys.First().Value.First();

        // Create token
        var t = h.CreateToken(
            null,
            null,
            (ClaimsIdentity)sessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.Identity,
            new Lifetime(sessionToken.ValidFrom, sessionToken.ValidTo),
            new SigningCredentials(
                securityKey,
                Algorithms.HmacSha256Signature,
                Algorithms.Sha256Digest));

        // Serialize token for validaiton
        var s = h.WriteToken(t);

        // Validate token
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            AllowedAudience = audience,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            SigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(Convert.FromBase64String(signingKey))
        };

        h.ValidateToken(s, validationParameters);

        // Return token with correct type
        return h.ReadToken(s) as JwtSecurityToken;
    }

    return null;
}

[Test]
public void GetToken_WhenValidSessionTokenExist_ShouldReturnValidJwtToken()
{
    JwtSecurityToken c;
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadJwtTokenFromCookie(container.GetInstance<ISecurityTokenOperations>(), out c)

    Assert.That(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.RawData));
}
```